# Error with Gmail. App

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to run the script above. I have a google spreadsheet that I included a Menu to. I want to be able to have a template ready to be sent when any of the options under the Menu, Email List, are clicked. I am new to this and I am trying to run the script below but I am getting an error. I am attaching the script. Could anyone help me understand what is the problem here?

```
function onOpen() {
  var subMenus = [{name:"Title 1", functionName: "t1"},
        {name:"Title2", functionName: "t2"},
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Email List", subMenus);
}

function t1() {
  var address = "test@test.com"  
  var body = "Dear Employee," +
      "Today You didnt request your logon time" +
      "Sincerely,"
    "Your Name"
    "Thank you";
  MailApp.sendEmail(address,body);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of basic syntax errors on your code, the script editor does not even allow it be saved. But the only "logic" problem I saw in it, is that you forgot the `subject` parameter on the `MailApp.sendEmail` call. Here is the *fixed* code:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var subMenus = [{name:"Title 1", functionName: "t1"},
                  {name:"Title2", functionName: "t2"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Email List", subMenus);
}

function t1() {
  var address = "test@test.com";
  var body = "Dear Employee," +
      "Today You didnt request your logon time"+
      "Sincerely,"+
      "Your Name"+
      "Thank you";

  var subject = "subject example";
  MailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Henrique! I continue working on this but I have taken it to anoter level. I am trying to modify a gdoc that already existed with two variables that the user inputs.

Comment: You're welcome. And since you're new here in StackOverflow. You should mark an answer as accepted when your question is answered.